# jQuery .stop() with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm working on a site and I'm trying to make sort of hover see a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/PBbSh/6/ but as you can see does `.stop()` not work here. Does somebody know why?

Comment: But I will recommend you to use `hoverIntent` http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 2):

Try doing `.stop(true, true)` instead. [The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) specifies stop as being

> `.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`

Doing `.stop(true, true)` will clear the queue and jump the animation to the end. If you just want to clear the animation queue, do `.stop(true, false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of stop, use .clearQueue()

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".projectenfoto1").stop().mouseover( projectenfunction(".projectenfoto1"));
$(".projectenfoto2").stop().mouseover( projectenfunction(".projectenfoto2"));
$(".projectenfoto3").stop().mouseover( projectenfunction(".projectenfoto3"));

function projectenfunction(foto1){
    $(foto1).stop().mouseover (function(){
        $(foto1).animate({
            width: "278",
            }, 500);
        });

    $(foto1).clearQueue.mouseout(function(){
        $(foto1).animate({
        width: "186.75",
    }, 500);
    });
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this optimized code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".projectenfoto1, .projectenfoto2, .projectenfoto3")
    .mouseover(function(){
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                width: "278",
                }, 500);
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({
            width: "186.75",
        }, 500);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I've cleaned up your HTML, CSS and jQuery a bit for clarity)

HTML:

```
<div id="fotowrapper">
        <div id="fotocontainer">

            <div class="projectenfoto1">
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fotowrapper {
    margin-top: 11px;
}

#fotocontainer {
    width: 747px;
    height: 523px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position:relative;
}

.projectenfoto1 {
    width: 186.75px;
    height: 378px;
    background-image: url(http://www.crewtime.nl/kookenleer/Images/Slideshow/foto3.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float:left;
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    projectenfunction(".projectenfoto1");

    function projectenfunction(foto1){

        $(foto1).mouseover (function(){
            $(foto1).stop().animate({
                width: "278"
            }, 500);
        });

        $(foto1).stop().mouseout(function(){
            $(foto1).stop().animate({
                width: "186.75"
            }, 500);
        });
    }
});
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PBbSh/10/